# Is there a parameter to set a penalty threshold in sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression, lasso-regression

I am fitting an `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression` model to my data with an L1 penalty as part of a feature selection process. It is my understanding that using `penalty='l1'` means that the optimization process will minimize a cost function subject to the sum of the absolute value of all coefficients being less than a given threshold ([as explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)#Basic_form)).

Is there a parameter to declare a threshold for the sum of the absolute value of the coefficients?

Here's my classifier:

```py
clf = LogisticRegression(penalty='l1', dual=False, tol=0.01, C=1.0,
                         fit_intercept=True, intercept_scaling=1,
                         random_state=0, solver='saga', max_iter=500,
                         multi_class='auto', n_jobs=-1)
```

Perhaps none of the `solver` options optimize the problem with a threshold, but honestly, I am only familiar with the algorithm in its basic form, so I don't know if that's the case or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for is the `C` parameter which is basically inverted lambda in the

`min: 1/n * ||y - X * beta||^2 + lambda * ||beta||`

equation from wiki (the [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lasso_(statistics)#Basic_form) that you have provided).

Decreasing `C` has the same effect as increasing lambda in the above equation (both, increasing lambda in the above equation and decreasing `C` in your code will lead to more regularization).

`tol` is used as a stopping criterion for the optimization algorithm, not for regularization.

Comment: Oh, great! By inverted lambda you mean 1/lambda, right?

Comment: Basically yes. As a consequence, you cannot set it to 0.